# How do implement a breadth first traversal?

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

This is what I have. I thought pre-order was the same and mixed it up with depth first!

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class Exercise25_1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree(new Integer[] {10, 5, 15, 12, 4, 8 });

    System.out.print("\nInorder: ");
    tree.inorder();
    System.out.print("\nPreorder: ");
    tree.preorder();
    System.out.print("\nPostorder: ");
    tree.postorder();

    //call the breadth method to test it

    System.out.print("\nBreadthFirst:");
    tree.breadth();

  }
}

class BinaryTree {
  private TreeNode root;


  /** Create a default binary tree */
  public BinaryTree() {
  }

  /** Create a binary tree from an array of objects */
  public BinaryTree(Object[] objects) {
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
      insert(objects[i]);
    }
  }

  /** Search element o in this binary tree */
  public boolean search(Object o) {
    return search(o, root);
  }

  public boolean search(Object o, TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
      return false;
    }
    if (root.element.equals(o)) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return search(o, root.left) || search(o, root.right);
    }
  }

  /** Return the number of nodes in this binary tree */
  public int size() {
    return size(root);
  }

  public int size(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
      return 0;
    }
    else {
      return 1 + size(root.left) + size(root.right);
    }
  }

  /** Return the depth of this binary tree. Depth is the
  * number of the nodes in the longest path of the tree */
  public int depth() {
    return depth(root);
  }

  public int depth(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
      return 0;
    }
    else {
      return 1 + Math.max(depth(root.left), depth(root.right));
    }
  }

  /** Insert element o into the binary tree
  * Return true if the element is inserted successfully */
  public boolean insert(Object o) {
    if (root == null) {
      root = new TreeNode(o); // Create a new root
    }
    else {
      // Locate the parent node
      TreeNode parent = null;
      TreeNode current = root;
      while (current != null) {
        if (((Comparable)o).compareTo(current.element) < 0) {
          parent = current;
          current = current.left;
        }
        else if (((Comparable)o).compareTo(current.element) > 0) {
          parent = current;
          current = current.right;
        }
        else {
          return false; // Duplicate node not inserted
        }
      }

      // Create the new node and attach it to the parent node
      if (((Comparable)o).compareTo(parent.element) < 0) {
        parent.left = new TreeNode(o);
      }
      else {
        parent.right = new TreeNode(o);
      }
    }

    return true; // Element inserted
  }

  public void breadth() {
  breadth(root);
  }

//  Implement this method to produce a breadth first

//  search traversal
  public void breadth(TreeNode root){
      if (root == null)
          return;

      System.out.print(root.element + " ");
      breadth(root.left);
      breadth(root.right);
 }


  /** Inorder traversal */
  public void inorder() {
    inorder(root);
  }

  /** Inorder traversal from a subtree */
  private void inorder(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
      return;
    }
    inorder(root.left);
    System.out.print(root.element + " ");
    inorder(root.right);
  }

  /** Postorder traversal */
  public void postorder() {
    postorder(root);
  }

  /** Postorder traversal from a subtree */
  private void postorder(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
      return;
    }
    postorder(root.left);
    postorder(root.right);
    System.out.print(root.element + " ");
  }

  /** Preorder traversal */
  public void preorder() {
    preorder(root);
  }

  /** Preorder traversal from a subtree */
  private void preorder(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
      return;
    }
    System.out.print(root.element + " ");
    preorder(root.left);
    preorder(root.right);

  }

  /** Inner class tree node */
  private class TreeNode {
    Object element;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;

    public TreeNode(Object o) {
      element = o;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exactly you want, if you're not looking for an answer?

Comment: well I cant seem to find out how to do a breadth first traversal in my book....it is practice...not homework. point in the right direction...

Answer (score 116):

Breadth first search

```
Queue<TreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<BinaryTree.TreeNode>() ;
public void breadth(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null)
        return;
    queue.clear();
    queue.add(root);
    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        TreeNode node = queue.remove();
        System.out.print(node.element + " ");
        if(node.left != null) queue.add(node.left);
        if(node.right != null) queue.add(node.right);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why is the queue declared outside of the method?  This will fail if breadth() is called twice concurrently. I can't see any downside of moving it inside as a local variable.

Comment: @Jonah in the case that `breadth()` is called twice _concurrently_, there is only one queue so it will have the elements added twice and randomly pulled by either of the two invocations, not to mention the fact that `LinkedList` is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 50):

Breadth first is a queue, depth first is a stack.

For breadth first, add all children to the queue, then pull the head and do a breadth first search on it, using the same queue.

For depth first, add all children to the stack, then pop and do a depth first on that node, using the same stack.

Comment: and a example - [here](http://edgblog.wordpress.com/2007/11/28/binary-tree-traversal/)

Comment: [LaValle](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/ch2.pdf), Sec.2.2 provides an excellent unified treatment of BFS, DFS, as well as other search methods.

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't seem like you're asking for an implementation, so I'll try to explain the process.

Use a Queue.  Add the root node to the Queue.  Have a loop run until the queue is empty.  Inside the loop dequeue the first element and print it out.  Then add all its children to the back of the queue (usually going from left to right).

When the queue is empty every element should have been printed out.

Also, there is a good explanation of breadth first search on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Answer (score 8):

```
public void breadthFirstSearch(Node root, Consumer<String> c) {
    List<Node> queue = new LinkedList<>();

    queue.add(root);

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Node n = queue.remove(0);
        c.accept(n.value);

        if (n.left != null)
            queue.add(n.left);
        if (n.right != null)
            queue.add(n.right);
    }
}
```

And the Node:

```
public static class Node {
    String value;
    Node left;
    Node right;

    public Node(final String value, final Node left, final Node right) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
//traverse
public void traverse()
{
    if(node == null)
        System.out.println("Empty tree");
    else
    {
        Queue<Node> q= new LinkedList<Node>();
        q.add(node);
        while(q.peek() != null)
        {
            Node temp = q.remove();
            System.out.println(temp.getData());
            if(temp.left != null)
                q.add(temp.left);
            if(temp.right != null)
                q.add(temp.right);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This code which you have written, is not producing correct BFS traversal:
(This is the code you claimed is BFS, but in fact this is DFS!)

```
//  search traversal
  public void breadth(TreeNode root){
      if (root == null)
          return;

      System.out.print(root.element + " ");
      breadth(root.left);
      breadth(root.right);
 }
```

Comment: This is Depth-first (pre-order traversal).

Comment: @Kreisquadratur, did you read my comment above the code? I meant "your code, which I copied below is not BFS". No one mentioned that. But this code is not BFS, it is DFS. (I updated a little to be more clear)

Comment: @Kreisquadratur That's ok. My wrong :) (Please take back your down vote)

Answer (score 1):

For implementing the breadth first search, you should use a queue. You should push the children of a node to the queue (left then right) and then visit the node (print data). Then, yo should remove the node from the queue. You should continue this process till the queue becomes empty. You can see my implementation of the BFS here: https://github.com/m-vahidalizadeh/foundations/blob/master/src/algorithms/TreeTraverse.java

Answer (score 0):

Use the following algorithm to traverse in breadth first search-

1. First add the root node into the queue with the put method.
2. Iterate while the queue is not empty.
3. Get the first node in the queue, and then print its value.
4. Add both left and right children into the queue (if the current
   nodehas children).
5. Done. We will print the value of each node, level by level,by
   poping/removing the element

Code is written below-

```
    Queue<TreeNode> queue= new LinkedList<>();
    private void breadthWiseTraversal(TreeNode root) {
        if(root==null){
            return;
        }
        TreeNode temp = root;
        queue.clear();
        ((LinkedList<TreeNode>) queue).add(temp);
        while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            TreeNode ref= queue.remove();
            System.out.print(ref.data+" ");
            if(ref.left!=null) {
                ((LinkedList<TreeNode>) queue).add(ref.left);
            }
            if(ref.right!=null) {
                ((LinkedList<TreeNode>) queue).add(ref.right);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a simple BFS implementation for BinaryTree with java 8 syntax.

```
void bfsTraverse(Node node, Queue<Node> tq) {
    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.print(" " + node.value);
    Optional.ofNullable(node.left).ifPresent(tq::add);
    Optional.ofNullable(node.right).ifPresent(tq::add);
    bfsTraverse(tq.poll(), tq);
}
```

Then invoke this with root node and a Java Queue implementation

```
bfsTraverse(root, new LinkedList<>());
```

Even better if it is regular tree, could use following line instead as there is not only left and right nodes.

```
Optional.ofNullable(node.getChildern()).ifPresent(tq::addAll);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
public static boolean BFS(ListNode n, int x){
        if(n==null){
           return false;
       }
Queue<ListNode<Integer>> q = new Queue<ListNode<Integer>>();
ListNode<Integer> tmp = new ListNode<Integer>(); 
q.enqueue(n);
tmp = q.dequeue();
if(tmp.val == x){
    return true;
}
while(tmp != null){
    for(ListNode<Integer> child: n.getChildren()){
        if(child.val == x){
            return true;
        }
        q.enqueue(child);
    }

    tmp = q.dequeue();
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that you need queue here at all.