# Depth-first search use of stack

Tags: graph, depth-first-search

Can someone please clear the use of stack in depth-first first search?

Q. How to keep a track of the visited vertices that have already been popped? Do i put it in an array or what?

Also, please tell me about the time complexity, space complexity and the use of array and link list in depth-first search

Answer (score 1):

Depth-first search-To travel as deep as possible from neighbour to neighbour before backtracking.

[for further](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844193/what-is-the-time-and-space-complexity-of-a-breath-first-and-depth-first-tree-tra)

Comment: I get that. But when all vertices have been popped out of the stack (im using stack for storing and then backtracking), what code do i write to tell the computer to that those vertices have already been visited? 

stupid question maybe but im new to all this with no background so please