# PHP Binary Search Tree, How to Traverse

Tags: php, algorithm

Well i build a basic Binary Search Tree using a class called `Node` for simplicity i will include the core method that is used to `insert` Nodes

```
public function addNode($node)
    {
        if ($this->left == null && $node->getValue() < $this->value) {
            $this->left = $node;
            $this->left->parent = $this;
            return;
        }

        if ($this->right == null && $node->getValue() > $this->value) {
            $this->right = $node;
            $this->right->parent = $this;
            return;
        }

        if ($node->getValue() < $this->getValue()) {
            $this->left->addNode($node);
            return;
        }

        if ($node->getValue() > $this->getValue()) {
            $this->right->addNode($node);
            return;
        }

    }
```

i have these basic member vars in the Node class

```
    private $left = null;

private $right = null;

private $value = null;

private $parent = null;
```

I can construct a tree by simply adding nodes to it.

```
$node = new Node(5);
$node->addNode(new Node(7));
$node->addNode(new Node(3));
$node->addNode(new Node(4));
```

Now the question is how do i traverse the tree if i want to print a nice text diagram of the tree. I am confused on how to traverse right on a specific level of the tree. did i miss an important variable when constructing the tree?

Comment: Traversing right is one of two cases: If we are left, $parent->right is right of us. If we are right, we must escalate to $parent->parent and use the leftmost path back down to our level.

Comment: @EugenRieck in order to print the tree i would need to traverse right across subtrees right?

Comment: That depends on your definition of "printing" - if you can position the elements freely (e.g. with "position: absolute"), you can just draw them "as they come" (traversing the tree by normally using the left path, but if it doesn't exist or was already drawn, chose the right one).

Comment: @EugenRieck for example like this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965335/how-to-print-binary-tree-diagram/4973083#4973083 i don't understand how the maxvalue is returned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer would depend on what order you want to traverse the tree, but a general depth-first traversal would look like:

```
function traverseTree($rootNode) {
    if($rootNode->left != null)
        traverseTree($rootNode->left);
    if($rootNode->right != null)
        traverseTree($rootNode->right);
    echo $rootNode->value;
}
```

From the comment you want breadth-first traversal. See this question about breadth-first traversal in Java. You can apply the same algorithm. [How do implement a breadth first traversal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262308/how-do-implement-a-breadth-first-traversal)

Comment: to print the tree i need to traverse the same depth across multiple subtree nodes. how do i do that is my question. Thanks for your comment also.

Comment: Ok Thanks. let me see it.

Answer (score 4):

A breadth first traversal is what you looking for:

```
printTree($root) {
    $queue = array($root);
    while ( count($queue) ) {
        $node = array_shift($queue);
        echo $node;
        if($node->left != null)
            array_unshift($node->left);
        if($node->right != null)
            array_unshift($node->right);
    }
}
```

Well Samuel already told you about breadth first traversal as I was writing this little function but still... I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: there is a issue with this code you need to add the new elements to the end of the queue, your not doing that please correct it