# Java graphs Breadth first

Tags: java, graph, breadth-first-search

how do I implement these methods in a Java Breadth first graph while using Queues?

An add method which adds a new vertex into the graph without any edges?

How can I return the Adjacency matrix?

if it contains a Triangle?

Comment: Please do your own homework. :)

Comment: Please do your own google

Comment: Learn BFS first. You will get all your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure what you're asking, you might want to take a look at [this question and answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262308/how-do-implement-a-breadth-first-traversal)

There you will find the description and implementation of a breadth-first search algorithm using `Queue` in Java.